# Event toggle listener

Tags: javascript, css, object, methods, selectors-api

I'm trying to change some styles with the `ui.activeFilter()` method but it says:

> Cannot read property `toggle` of `undefined`.

And I set the variable `filterLinks` to global scope. I can't figure why it's not working.

```
"use strict";

// UI elements
const filterLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const itemsLeft = document.querySelectorAll('span');

// Event listeners
filterLinks.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', check);
});

// Laptops
class Laptop {
    constructor(availability, price, brand) {
      this.availability = availability;
      this.price = price;
      this.brand = brand;
    }
}

// Filter methods
class UiMethod {
    activeFilter(dddd) {
        dddd.classList.toggle('checked');

        if(dddd.className === 'checked') {
            console.log("test");
        } else {
            console.log('Try again you can do it, you are close to the succes');
        }
    }
}

const ui = new UiMethod;

// Function helpers
function check(e) {

    ui.activeFilter(filterLinks);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution, your `check(e)` function needs a slight update. Instead of passing the entire object, you just need to pass the `e.target` of the click function to only affect that object.

**change:**
`ui.activeFilter(filterLinks);`

**to:**
 `ui.activeFilter(e.target);`

```js
"use strict";

// UI elements
const filterLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Event listeners
filterLinks.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', check);
});

// Laptops
class Laptop {
    constructor(availability, price, brand) {
      this.availability = availability;
      this.price = price;
      this.brand = brand;
    }
}

// Filter methods
class UiMethod {
    activeFilter(dddd) {
        dddd.classList.toggle('checked');

        if(dddd.className === 'checked') {
            console.log("test");
        } else {
            console.log('Try again you can do it, you are close to the succes');
        }
    }
}

const ui = new UiMethod;

// Function helpers
function check(e) {
    ui.activeFilter(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.checked{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a><BR>
<a href="#">test2</a><BR>
<a href="#">test3</a>
```

Comment: ok i tried with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and it worked the same way i added e.target. Which way is better ?

Comment: @GrecA when `check(e)` is called, not only is `event` passed as `e`, but `this` references the object that was being clicked on at that is it. It actually has nothing to do with `filterLinks`. As far as `this` is concerned, `filterLinks` doesn't exist.

Comment: @GrecA, for consistency I would use `e.target`. I normally use jquery so this means something different. However, passing one of those two is the solution to your problem (no matter if you pass `this` or `e.target`).

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot read property `toggle` of undefined.

Looks like `toggle` is referenced here: `dddd.classList.toggle`. Therefore, `dddd.classList` is undefined. `classList` is a defined property on all DOM element objects, so `dddd` must not be what you think it is.

Looking back at the definition for `dddd`, we can see that it's defined as `filterLinks`. Looking at `filterLinks`, it is clear that it is set by `document.querySelectorAll('a')`.

Examining the documentation for [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) tells us that  it returns:

> A non-live `NodeList` containing one `Element` object for each element that matches at least one of the specified selectors or an empty `NodeList` in case of no matches.

So to access the actual DOM element object found by the query, we need to pull that object from the `NodeList`. If you want to perform the `toggle` operation on *every* element that is found, the simplest way to do so is to loop through the `NodeList` and run the function on every element. A `NodeList` is array-like, but it is not an array, so we need to convert it to an array to be able to use `forEach` on it. This results in the following code:

```
Array.from(dddd).forEach(element => element.classList.toggle('checked'));
```

which would replace this:

```
dddd.classList.toggle('checked');
```

Comment: Yes but if i add this it enables every element simultaneous, i want individual element to toggle that class.

Comment: Then use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns the _first_ element matching the selector, and make your selector more specific.

Comment: i let the [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and i added e.target.classList.toggle('checked');

This means that for every target clicked right? Is this correct?